# C++ typedef versus using

Tags: c++, typedef, using

I recently saw some code along the lines:

```
typedef QuiteALongName::SomeVariable SomeVariable;
```

My first thought was that it might be better to  write the code as:

```
using QuiteALongName::SomeVariable;
```

But, being a bit rusty, I couldn't quite put my finger on what the differences would be, or whether there were any 'gotchas' to look out for using either approach. Can anyone offer some wisdom?

Comment: versus??? they are quite different things.

Comment: @haccks Not related. That said, C++11 renders `typedef` obsolete. I’m all in favour of dropping it completely.

Comment: @Rakibul: Agreed, but in this case the typedef is specifically being used to remove the need to fully qualify the `SomeVariable` type, which is essentially the purpose of `using` is it not?